# Rails: use blank? in where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model that has start and stop dates.  If the stop date is empty or nil, then the model is in active state.

I'm trying to add a scope for all active instances.

Can I use blank? in the where clause somehow?  Is my only approach to check for both in the where clause?  Is there another way to do this?

Here's what I have now:

```
scope :active, where( 'stop_date is ? or stop_date is ""', nil )
```

I'm hoping there's a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that after rails 3.1.0 `scope` [is deprecated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope) so I would consider just using class methods. If the column can actually be `NULL` and empty counts as `NULL` as well in your situation then you will have to check for both instances as such:

```
def self.active
  where("stop_date IS NULL OR stop_date <> ''")
end
```

Is a bit nicer IMO, but if you do not need to check for `NULL` state (like in the instance where `null => false`). Then just:

```
def self.active
  where("stop_date <> ''")
end
```

will work.